# Excel VBA Screenupdating does not work when accessing network drives

Tags: excel, vba, networking, screenupdating

I have a workbook with a moderate amount of VBA code that opens, saves and copies between many Excel files. It utilizes Application.ScreenUpdating = False to prevent the user from seeing the many file opens, saves, etc. It works fine when the Excel files are located on my "C" drive, but when they are located on a network drive, the ScreenUpdating is not suppressed.

Several "Debug.Print Application.ScreenUpdating" statements throughout the code all report "False" and a Watch for change in value does not trigger, but the ScreenUpdating is not suppressed.
I use global constants to define the location of the folders, so I can quickly change them and see a distinct difference.

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer to why, but maybe `Application.Visible = False` might help

Comment: Thanks Chris, I appreciate the help, but I also need to display a user form with a progress indicator.